# Getting every offsetParent or the total offSetTop and total offSetLeft

Tags: javascript, jquery, offset, offsetof

I want to get the total offSetTop and the total offSetLeft of a child element which have many level of parent element and may be adding up.

Is that any shorthand way, besides of adding one by one in manual ways?

Comment: This seems like a decent script  http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using jQuery: `$( node ).offset()`  then `.top` and `.left`

Answer (score 14):

To provide an answer without jQuery:

```
var a = Element, b = 0, c = 0;
while (a) {
    b += a.offsetLeft;
    c += a.offsetTop;
    a = a.offsetParent;
}
```

Where `Element` is your Element node for which you need an `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop`.

Comment: works good :) but for me, `c += a.offsetTop - a.scrollTop;` yields correct position just in case that some parents has scrolled.

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

> If you need the bounding rectangle relative to the top-left corner of the document, just add the current scrolling position to the top and left properties (these can be obtained using window.scrollX and window.scrollY) to get a bounding rectangle which is independent from the current scrolling position.

```
let { left, top } = domNode.getBoundingClientRect();
left += window.scrollX;
top += window.scrollY;
```